# ?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless doesn't work in ImageView inside Toolbar Android Studio

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, imageview, android-toolbar

I'm trying to make ripple effect in ImageView inside Toolbar using

```
android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
android:clickable="true"
```

But when I run the app, the output is looks like `?attr/selectableItemBackground`. Then I'm trying to change `Toolbar` to `RelativeLayout`. It's work, but I need to use Toolbar instead of RelativeLayout.

I'm also try it using `android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"`. But there's no ripple effect if I use `android:background`. Here's my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorGrey"
    tools:context=".User.BottomNavigationView.Student.StudentDetailActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/student_detail_app_bar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ActionBarTextColor">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/student_detail_collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:title="Detail Siswa">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/student_detail_profile_picture_image_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/img1"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/student_detail_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?android:actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/student_detail_back_button_image_view"
                    android:layout_width="30dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
                    android:padding="3dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/general_back_button"
                    app:tint="@color/colorPrimaryIcon" />

            </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/colorGrey"
        app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior">

    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
    
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I want to use `?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless` or `circular ripple effect` in ImageView inside Toolbar. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add **focusable** true it will work

```
android:focusable="true"
```

Below I have added clickable and focusable code

```
android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
android:clickable="true"
android:focusable="true"
```

Comment: It's work, but I still got a rectangle ripple effect. I want it to be a circle ripple

Comment: I think your using vector asset and assinging in android:src="", replace with android:backgrund and try it.

Answer (score 0):

You should use container to hold ImageView with selectableItemBackgroundBorderless and set padding in parent view or set layout_margin to ImageView.
Here is my suggestion:

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
android:id="@+id/student_detail_toolbar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="?android:actionBarSize"
app:layout_collapseMode="pin">

<FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
        android:padding="4dp">

    <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/student_detail_back_button_image_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
                android:src="@drawable/general_back_button"
                app:tint="@color/colorPrimaryIcon" />


</FrameLayout>
```

</androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>